# aplay not working on Ubuntu 11.04 for root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04, alsa

I have ALSA on Ubuntu 11.04 version.
When I play aplay through my normal user, I am able to get the output.
When I do this with the root user, the command hangs: below stuff happens

```
root@myuser:~# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
```

(hangs)

Also if I export the $HOME to /home/myuser/ then it works. So whats wrong for running the aplay command with a root.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. If you want to figure out what is wrong - debug it. Why don't you start with `strace` and see at what point it hangs up?

Aside from that, why on earth do you need to run it with root privileges?

Comment: Whats the command to check the trace? Also the application which I have build needs to fire the aplay with root privileges...

Comment: Using strace - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-to-use-strace